# Bootstrap: Panel-Title not breaking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

This is my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 400px;">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="button">
    <h3 class="panel-title">asdfasdfsadfa asdfasdfasdfasdfdsd <i aria-hidden="true" class="far fa-lg fa-pull-right fa-fw fa-square"></i></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dvL6hkpg/1/).

As long as the panel is big enough the text and the FontAwesome icon are inline. However, once the width decreases, it does not break the word and the icon just drops to the next line.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Try to add `display:inline`. https://jsfiddle.net/dvL6hkpg/8/

Comment: @Timggwp It should stay responsive though. The `width` I added is just to demonstrate the effect.

Comment: I think it works even without `width` property

Comment: Please check this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Yagg8wc.png).

Comment: Do you want it to be on the same line and you want that `<i>` element to become on top of the text when you resize?

Comment: Or you want it to be in the middle always?

Comment: It should look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/2Txaovk.png). So once the `<i>` element is in the next line the text should break as well. Currently the text only breaks after a specific width.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dvL6hkpg/11/ try this now